# WSO2 API Manager - TypeError Failed to Fetch in API Try Out

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have configured **WSO2 API Manager *4.0.0*** in an AWS EC2 which runs on Amazon Linux 2. I am following [this WSO2 documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/api-manager-quick-start-guide/) to setup my first API. I am accessing the API Manager's Dev Portal via my local machine. I am in Step 3 : Invoking my API.

When I click the Execute button under Try Out for GET requests, I get a 200 OK response, but with an error saying `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. I have attached a screenshot here.

I feel that the request URL mentioned here ( `https://localhost:8243/hello/1.0.0` ) should have the EC2 server's IP address, instead of `localhost` , but I cannot find a way to modify that. What am I doing wrong here?

**Output**
[image]

**Browser's Inspect Console Tab**
[image]

Comment: You can edit the `localhost:8243` by updating the `gateway.environment` configurations in the `deployment.toml`. But, before that, can you share a screenshot of the Browser's Console tab while performing the Execute? To make sure that this is not happening due to CORS.

Comment: @Athiththan Hi, I updated the question with that.

Answer (score 1):

The Swagger was not able to make the invocation, as it is getting refused. Try updating the API Gateway Environment configurations in the `deployment.toml` to the Hostnames / IP address (publicly accessible) of the EC2 instance.

Following is a sample TOML configuration of API Gateway Environments. Update the  `<change-this>` with appropriate hostnames.

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
...
ws_endpoint = "ws://<change-this>:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://<change-this>:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://<change-this>:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://<change-this>:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://<change-this>:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://<change-this>:8021"
```

Once the configurations are done, restart the server and invoke the API from the Devportal Swagger UI.

Comment: Okay I am gonna try this. So, this is not a CORS issue, then?

Comment: No, this is not a CORS issue. If it is, then you will find warn traces mentioning that this header is missing and CORS restricted the invocation.